# Integral smaller than $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

As $\xi \rightarrow \pm \infty$. We prove only the first result; the second is proved in a very similar way to the first. Choose $\varepsilon >0$. Because $f \in L^{1} (\textbf{R})$, there exists and $M>0$ such that $$\int_{\left | x \right |>M} \left |  f(x)\right | dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-M} \left |  f(x)\right | dx + \int_{M}^{\infty} \left |  f(x)\right | dx < \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon.$$

I was going through a proof and I do not know if I am interpreting this inequality well. 
Is M big enough to be so close to infinity so that $\int_{\infty}^{-M}|f(x)|dx+\int_{\infty}^{-M}|f(x)|dx<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$?
Or is there another interpretation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there's an issue with the image you intended to include

Comment: If the integral is going to converge, nearly the entire area under the curve (all but $\epsilon$) will be between $-M<x<M$ with some de minimis amount in the tails.  The expression above says we can choose $M$ such that the area in each tail will be less than $\frac \epsilon2$

Comment: Since $\int |f|\,dx<\infty$, then for any given $\epsilon' >0$ there is a number $M$ that depends on $\epsilon'$ such that $\int_{|x|>M}f\,dx<\epsilon'$.  Now take $\epsilon'=\epsilon/2$.